# How to check massive availability of domain names using PHP?

Tags: php

How do I check the domain availability of every domain in a long list? For example, I would like to choose a base word, e.g. "overflow" and check for domain availability of all 3-letter combinations after the word, e.g. "overflowabc"

Is there a script written for this? Is it legal to do a massive search like this?

Comment: What is "domain availability"?

Comment: there are Whois apis where you query for domains name and details, but some cost to use and have limitation of course.

Comment: Typosquatting is so boring. We are in 2012, come on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `checkdnsrr` function to perform a domain name look up:

```
if (checkdnsrr($domain, 'A')) {
    ...
}
```

It is illegal to scrape DNS registries in some countries, but you are not really scraping, just looking for availability. So it should be fine.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php